# Nuxt 3 - how to access plugin injections from components?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Using Nuxt 3 and [vue-gtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag), what is the right way to access `$gtag` from components?

plugins/gtag.client.js:

```
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const router = useRouter();
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(
    VueGtag,
    {
      config: {
        id: '...'
      }
    },
    router
  );
});
```

In Nuxt 2, `this.$gtag` was accessible from component file.

In Nuxt 3, I can't seem to find it:

```
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
nuxtApp.$gtag //undefined
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/blob/master/src/attach-api.js), it seems to be [defined correctly](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties), so I don't think it's a problem with the plugin itself.
`app.config.globalProperties.$gtag = api;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have same issue when define the domToImage plugin in nuxt 3. I found a solution as follow. Hope to help you.

- Return provide in nuxt plugin:

> ```
> import domtoimage from "dom-to-image-more";
> export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
>     // nuxtApp.vueApp.use(domtoimage)
>     return {
>         provide: {
>             domtoimage
>         }
>     }
> })
> ```

- Use in component:

> ```
> const print = () => {
>   console.log("Print ...")
>   const { $domtoimage } = useNuxtApp()
>   $domtoimage.toPng(printMeDiv)
>     .then((dataUrl) => {
>       console.log(dataUrl)
>     })
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create a plugin for nuxt3 and save them in `plugins/google-analytics.client.ts`

Then you must use `provide` to add `event`, `pageview`, `screenview`,... like this bellow code.

```
import VueGtag, {
    event,
    pageview,
    screenview
} from "vue-gtag";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    // @ts-ignore
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueGtag, {
       config: { id: config.public.googleAnalyticId }
    }, nuxtApp.$router);

    return {
        provide: {
            gtag: {
                event,
                pageview,
                screenview
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now, you can use `$gtag` as normal in your components.

```
....
async function handleSubmit(valid: any, { email, password }) {
  const { $gtag } = useNuxtApp()
  console.log('$gtag: ', $gtag)
  $gtag.event('login', {
    method: 'Local'
  })
  ....
....
```