# How to access $axios in composition API without using useContext

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I am trying to access $axios in Vue composition API without using `useContext()` because the current app is not a Nuxt app and is like a library that either can be used inside a Nuxt app or Vue app. So if I use $axios in the code then in Nuxt app it can be called serverside too. if anyone can help it would be very helpful, even if we can made this mechanism with inject/provide.

Comment: Did you try provide/inject and what did not work? It's basically how it's done. You can create custom composable that uses `inject('axios')` inside but it's basically the same

Comment: Actually I don't know how to access to the $axios from context. I even tried `getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$axios` but it seems `getCurrentInstance` is not defined in Nuxt app.

Comment: You don't need anything like this. In regular Vue portions use provide/inject In Nuxt it's something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410533/nuxt-3-how-to-access-plugin-injections-from-components . You may not need this at all as Axios is stateless, you can just import it

Comment: I think you did not get my question, I have to use $axios because it is what Nuxt use to make an API call in server side.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt 3 officially recommends using `$fetch` for making http request

> Note that $fetch is the preferred way to make HTTP calls in Nuxt 3 instead of @nuxt/http and @nuxtjs/axios that are made for Nuxt 2.
> https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/dollarfetch

However if you want to set it up for example to add headers, you can create a composable and work with it throughout the nuxt app

```js
import axios from "axios"; 
export const $axios = axios.create({ 
   baseURL: BASE_URL, 
   headers: { 
     ...headers
   }, 
});
```